# How to have a reference to a multi-dimensional pointer?

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer

This is just a curious question. Forgive me if this sounds dumb.

As per [dcl.ref/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.ref#5):

> There shall be no references to references, no arrays of references,
>   and no pointers to references.

I don't see in the standard that restricts a reference from pointing to a kD pointer.

So theoretically, since a pointer is a valid object, a variable can be a reference to a kD pointer.

However, I can't seem to prove it in this example having a reference to a 3D pointer.

```
int p = 1, *p1 = &p, **p2 = &p1, ***p3 = &p2;
int &r = p3;
```

I get an error:

> error: invalid conversion from 'int***' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
>      int &r = p3; // error

Or other variations such as `int &&&r = p3`.

> error: cannot declare reference to 'int&&', which is not a typedef or
>   a template type argument

**Question(s)**:

1. How to have a reference to a kD (eg. 3D) pointer? (if possible)
    *if not: is there part of the standard that restricts such?*

*Unnecessary question:* 
*Why `int&&&` will have an error "not a typedef..." while `int&&` is valid? is there a limit to the `'&'`?*

Comment: Have you tried `auto& r = p3;`? This would indicate if the reference is valid.

Comment: `int ***(&r) = p3;` or `int &r = ***p3;` depending on what you actually want to see here.

Comment: You attempt to declare `r` as a reference to `int`, but `p3` is not an `int`.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe, yes I've tried and it works. just looking for the right combination of `*` and `&`

Comment: Also, the syntax with `&&` is special for [*rvalue references*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Rvalue_references).

Comment: @HenriMenke, please check https://wandbox.org/permlink/pP1xdPTc8OISXDtV, the first one shows the address of the 3D pointer. the latter isn't. apologies for the ambiguity. but I get it now,  appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to have a reference to a kD (eg. 3D) pointer? (if possible)

As pointed out by @Henri Menke,

Defining a reference to a **3**D pointer is:

```
int ***(&r) = p3;
```

In a more general sense, declaring a reference to a *k*-D pointer depends on the number of `*` in the declarator.

```
int ****&r = p4; // p4 is a 4-D pointer
```

reading from right to left starting from `r`, would be:

*a reference **to** a 4(number of asterisk)-D pointer of type `int`.*

> Why int&&& will have an error "not a typedef..." while int&& is valid?
>   is there a limit to the '&'?

As pointed out by @Some programmer dude:

the syntax with `&&` is special for [rvalue references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Rvalue_references).